# Magento 2.2 <preference> not working to override a model class

Tags: overrides, magento2.2, model, extend

I want to override a model call (**Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector**).

We used **preference** to override a model call inside di.XML like magento 2.1.x But it is not working on Magento 2.2

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" type="MyModule\CustomShippingTax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector" />

</config>
```

**app\code\MyModule\CustomShippingTax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector.php**

```
 <?php  

  namespace MyModule\CustomShippingTax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;
    /**
     * Tax totals calculation model
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    class CommonTaxCollector extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector
    {

        public function mapAddress(QuoteAddress $address)
        {
            $customerAddress = $this->customerAddressFactory->create();
            $customerAddress->setCountryId($address->getCountryId());
            $customerAddress->setRegion(
                $this->customerAddressRegionFactory->create()->setRegionId($address->getRegionId())
            );
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();


    var_dump($address->getPostcode());
    exit;

            $customerAddress->setCity($address->getCity());
            $customerAddress->setStreet($address->getStreet());

            return $customerAddress;
        }


    }
```

Please, can you help me on above issue?Any reference and suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal no error nothing.

Comment: Try my code from answer.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal thanks for the answer I have tried but not working.

Comment: Can you please try my code again with both the files.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, Again I have tried but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since dependency injection did not work on **CommonTaxCollector** class, alternatively you can override method(s) using dependency injection on other files (mentioned below in di.xml) which are extending the class ***Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector***

> app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" />
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal" />
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Shipping" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Shipping" />
</config>
```

OR

**Try following code:**

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector">
        <plugin name="[vendorname]_[modulename]_commontaxcollector" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\CommonTaxCollectorPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/CommonTaxCollectorPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin;

class CommonTaxCollectorPlugin
{
    public function afterMapAddress(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector $subject,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address $customerAddress
    ) {
        var_dump($customerAddress->getPostcode());die;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Output of var_dump is display in console, check action ***estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id***

Comment: Thanks!!! It's Working.But why preference is not working?

Comment: @KamleshJha - Review updated answer.

Comment: Hi Pratik, can you explain please what is dependency injection in context of magento 2. how can i check that dependency injection is not working on particular class

Comment: @PratikOza Not working for me. I tried both way. Any idea why ?

Comment: I am using Plugin way, 

public function aroundMapItem(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector $subject,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $itemDataObjectFactory,
        AbstractItem $item,
        $priceIncludesTax,
        $useBaseCurrency,
        $parentCode = null
    ) {
//My Content 
}

Function is calling but not working.